# Error after installing R.2.0, showing "Fatal error:'R_TempDir' contains space

Tags: r

I wanted to update my older version of R, therefore I uninstalled the older one and downloaded the current version 4.2.0. After installation, the GUI is showing- a fatal error:'R_TempDir' contains space. GUI closes as soon as I cancel the error pop-up. How should I tackle this problem?

[image]

Comment: What OS are you running? What was the older version of R that you were using? Where exactly does the GUI show this message? Like in a pop up? Is this in the RGUI itself or RStudio? Maybe posting a screen shot might make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks for asking friend. I am using windows 11. I was using 4.0.2 before. Yes, the error appears as pop up in RGUI itself. Please have a look at the screenshot.

Comment: Do you have an `.Rprofile` file in your home directory? Or do you have an `R_TempDir` environment variable set? I think the problem is that the path contains a space character. Perhaps your username has a space in it? Windows and R doesn't work all that well with file paths that have spaces in some cases. It looks like newer versions of R are trying to check for this and warn you more aggressively than older versions where errors would be silent.

Comment: Thank you very much friend for the suggestions. Yes, Username is with a space. But, I did not find .Rprofile file in home directory. Should i try to return to the older versions of R? or there is some way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue solved by following the below steps:-

1. Download both the files R 4.3 and Rstudio.
2. Disconnect the Internet.
3. Install both the files and now you are good to program in R.

Note: Also Make sure that the Environment variable is set.

The reason why this happens is due to some track/error/Performance reporting to Rstudio during your first installation.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new environment variable:

1. make a new folder and the location was C:\Temp
2. search for environment variable in your search bar you will see an "edit the system environment variable"
3. click on the "Environment variable..." in the bottom
4. make a new variable under user variables name it TMPDIR and the location of the folder you created mine was C:\Temp
   Try opening R first if it doesn't show the error then R is working properly then you can proceed with Rstudio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).